# Cannot implicitly convert type string to string[] in autocomplete method

Tags: c#, methods, autocomplete

Afternoon all - it's Friday th 13th so of course I am having an absolute mare!!!

The code below, 'should' create a list of items that will be used in a textbox autocomplete.

```
public string[] GetAutoComplete(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            string memberid = HttpContext.Current.Session["VDS_MemberID"].ToString(); 
            string locationid = HttpContext.Current.Session["VDS_LocationID"].ToString();
            string inhouse = HttpContext.Current.Session["VDS_Inhouse"].ToString();
            string supplier = HttpContext.Current.Session["VDS_Supplier"].ToString();
            string groupw = HttpContext.Current.Session["VDS_Group"].ToString();
            string external = HttpContext.Current.Session["VDS_External"].ToString();

            VDSORDAL.PDC_VDSOREntities autocomplete = new VDSORDAL.PDC_VDSOREntities();

            var r = (from p in  autocomplete.tblAutoCompletes
                    where p.MemberId == memberid && p.LocationId == locationid && p.ACItem.Contains(prefixText)
                    select p);

            if (inhouse != "DoNotDisplayInhouse")
                         r = r.Where(p => p.ACItem == inhouse);

            if (supplier != "DoNotDisplaySupplier")
                r = r.Where(p => p.ACItem == supplier);

            if (groupw != "DoNotDisplayGroup")
                r = r.Where(p => p.ACItem == groupw);

            if (external != "DoNotDisplayExternal")
                r = r.Where(p => p.ACItem == external);

            return r.Distinct().OrderBy(p => p.ACItem).ToString();

        }
```

However, I am getting the question title as an error.

Can anyone suggest a way around this? Apologies..I am having a bad day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly

```
return r.Distinct().OrderBy(p => p.ACItem).ToString();
```

should be

```
return r.Distinct().OrderBy(p => p.ACItem).ToArray();
```

**Update:**

Sounds like that's your real problem. Try (following code is brain-compiled)

```
return (from p in r orderby p.ACItem desc select p.ACItem).ToArray();
```

I'm assuming `ACItem` is the string you want to return, if not, select what you want in the array.

Or possibly

```
return (from p in r where p != null orderby p.ACItem desc select p.ACItem).ToArray();
```

the `where p != null` may be necessary, you pretty much need to inspect r and see what's in there, not really enough info to be able to answer this conclusively.
That said, `.ToArray` instead of `.ToString` is still the answer to your problem, anything else is a different question.

Comment: I've tried ToArray but then received a System.ArgumentNullException Error: Cannot implicitly converty type 'VDSORDAL.tblAutoComplete[]' to 'string[]'

Comment: OrderBy(...).Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

The last line should be:

```
return r.Distinct().OrderBy(p => p.ACItem).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a `ToString()`.  Use either `ToArray()` or `ConvertAll<string>().ToArray()`